# My puzzle on Project Euler # 25 about java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, algorithm

I am working on the Project Euler #25. I am intending to save all fibonacci number in a BigInteger array. However, there throws a NullPointerException, I don't know why and how to avoid it. I know there is much more simple algorithm to solve this question. But I just want to know where is my mistake, thank you very much! Here is the question states: The Fibonacci sequence is defined by the recurrence relation:

Fn = Fn−1 + Fn−2, where F1 = 1 and F2 = 1. Hence the first 12 terms will be:

F1 = 1 F2 = 1 F3 = 2 F4 = 3 F5 = 5 F6 = 8 F7 = 13 F8 = 21 F9 = 34 F10 = 55 F11 = 89 F12 = 144 The 12th term, F12, is the first term to contain three digits.

What is the first term in the Fibonacci sequence to contain 1000 digits?

My code is below:

```
  private static BigInteger[] fibonacci;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 0; fibonacci[fibonacci.length-1].toString().length() < 1000; i++){
            if(i == 0)
                fibonacci[i] = BigInteger.ZERO;
            if(i < 3)
                fibonacci[i] = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
            else
                fibonacci[i] = fibonacci[i - 1].add(fibonacci[i - 2]);
        }
        System.out.println(fibonacci.length);
    }
```

Comment: Do you understand *what* is `null`? If yes, you'll spot the error on your own.

Comment: That is quite inefficient memory-wise: since you don't know how many numbers you need to calculate, you will need to resize your array when you reach its capacity, which could take quite a lot of memory at some point. You only need to store two numbers at any one time to calculate the next one. I suggest you reviewed your algorithm.

Comment: Tip: the array has to be longer than 1000.

Answer (score 3):

You have not initialized the array `fibonacci`. You need to allocate memory before using the array.

```
private static BigInteger[] fibonacci = new BigInteger[1000]; // Some number x
```

I would recommend using a `List` instead of an array given that you don't know the size of array.

```
private static List<BigInteger> fibonacci = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
```

Also, if you are using arrays, `fibonacci[fibonacci.length - 1]` will not work because you are always checking for position 999 if you're initializing array size to 1000. For this to work, you have to use an `ArrayList` and then you can use

```
fibonacci[fibonacci.size() - 1]
```

Comment: OP didn't say he had no static initializer blocks!

Answer (score 3):

You never initialized your `fibonacci` array.

Just use

```
private static BigInteger[] fibonacci = new BigInteger[1000]();
```

or better extract the amount of Fibonacci numbers you want to calculate to a separate constant:

```
private static int amount = 1000;
private static BigInteger[] fibonacci = new BigInteger[amount]();;

public static void main(String[] args) {
  for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++){
    if(i == 0)
      fibonacci[i] = BigInteger.ZERO;
    else if(i < 3)
      fibonacci[i] = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
    else
      fibonacci[i] = fibonacci[i - 1].add(fibonacci[i - 2]);
}

System.out.println(fibonacci.length);
```